# Difference between SQL connection string (local) and .\

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Between SQL 2000 and 2005 MS changed the syntax to connect to a local database from (local) to .\instanceName.
I have a client who has been using (local)\instanceName to connect to local SQL Server 2005 databases. Usually it works fine, but sometimes it doesn't and he has been using PCname\instanceName. 
Why does this sometimes fail?

Comment: Is this PC in Network. If so, check any other PC in the network has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can define alias for your instance in sql server configuration manager. You can define multiple aliases for same instace, so both (loacl) and instanceName will work.

Comment: .\instancename and (local)\instancename work on my PC without setting up any aliases.   But on my clients network sometimes (local)\instancename does not work.  I just wanted to understand why.